# Execute each line of bash in separate terminals

Tags: php, laravel, bash, phpstorm

I have create a simple bash script for my laravel project (file name: bash-script.sh)

```
php artisan serv

php artisan queue:work --queue=first_queue

php artisan queue:work --queue=second_queue

php artisan queue:work --queue=third_queue

php artisan queue:work --queue=fourth_queue

php artisan schedule:work
```

the problem is I want each line of these commands to run in separate terminals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you, in the same terminal all processes responses:

```
php artisan serv &
php artisan queue:work --queue=first_queue &
php artisan queue:work --queue=second_queue &
php artisan queue:work --queue=third_queue &
php artisan queue:work --queue=fourth_queue &
php artisan schedule:work
```

The ampersand (&) it's for executing in another process and freeing the current execution, all outputs in every processes will write on the same terminal

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to run in a terminal window, you will have to start a terminal window.

```
xterm -e "php artisan serv"&
xterm -e "php artisan queue:work --queue=first_queue"&
xterm -e "php artisan queue:work --queue=second_queue"&

# et cetera
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you do not have a graphic environment on the host (ie you connect to the remote host via ssh) you need a terminal multiplexer like [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki)

For both, there are several howto and example all over the web